# get the key of Firebase Recycler view holder for deleting specific post on long click

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i had a **recycler view holder** which consist of comments for a post,i need to delete the comment on long press, but for that i need the **key** of that comment at the **position**.

In my bindview holder i have the code like below but it is showing me **error on getref() method that cannot reslove method getref(int)**

```
       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(final CommentViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Comm comment = mComments.get(position);


        final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
        final String postKey = postRef.getKey();
```

if I get the post key I can delete the comment.How can i get key of that specific comment?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is you have to make a callback from adapter to calling fragment/activity and remove the comment from list and call `notifyDataSetChange`() on your adapter.

The callback will have an `int position` as the parameter which can be used to get the object at given position and remove from list.

```
//your constructor for adapter

  private OnClickViewItemListener mItemListener;
     private List<Comm> listData;
        public YourAdapter(List<Comm> listData, OnClickViewItemListener mItemListener) {
            this.listData = listData;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mItemListener = mItemListener;
        }
```

Your adapter viewholder should have following changes.

```
 public CommentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mButton = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btDelete);
        mButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(final View v) {
                mItemListener.onClickViewItem(v,getAdapterPosition());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

now implement OnClickViewItemListener in your activity or fragment and do what ever you want.

```
 @Override
    public void onClickViewItem(View view, int position) {
        //here handle the item click listener
        // remove the comment here and notify adapter
       commList.remove(position);

    }
```